# Is it possible to have same potential in different branches of some circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I've been wondering. Can I check if 2 points on a circuit are the same branch with voltage check? What if both points happen to have the same potential, being them separated by high impedances? (so really different branches, but with the same potential, by chance) Is that possible?

If it is, then check with voltages might not be a cool idea always unless one knows the circuit, I guess. And I'd have to check the resistance instead (disconnect the circuit and measure it between the 2 points - would not work that well if a component becomes a short after turning on the circuit, but ok).

If it's not, then either resistance or voltage would do and would be easier (voltage can be measured with the circuit working - I believe resistance can't, right?).

Comment: `is it possible?` questions usually cannot be answered `no` ... that makes them practically useless

Comment: If I start with "When is it possible to (...)", for example, I'm implying it's possible. But I don't know if it is. How would you phrase the question?

Comment: in electrical circuits, what are some of the ways to have two unconnected points at the same voltage?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, of course two nodes can be at same potential.

For example two identical voltage dividers can have identical output voltage, so difference is 0V.

It is also possible that two unrelated nodes have the same voltage, because the impedance of the meter you use to measure the voltages actually sets them to the same potential.

Comment: So to see if 2 points are the same in a circuit, I should disconnect the power and measure the resistance between those 2 points with an ohmmeter? (Since checking voltage seems not to be effective, if I understood right.) And if the circuit must be connected, then I'd say I can only more or less guess, since same potential may be found on different branches, are your answer and AJN's say. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Bridge circuits (when balanced) and [opamps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_ground) in negative feedback configuration are two examples.